# How to parse a javascript array (containing JSON object as elements) from html response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, node.js

I am trying to write a nodejs script that fetches data from multiple collections in mongodb. after that the complete data has to be written into one json response.
Currently the approach i have taken is pushing the json data from each collection into an array, and then sending the array as a response. but in the client side script i am unable to read the data.
The code (Router.js) I have written to write the response is:

appTableProdSchema.js

```
var conn = require('mongoose');

module.exports = conn.model('AppTableProd', {
    snapShotTime : String,
    nfs: Array,    
    hive: Array,
    beeline: Array,
    hs2: Array,
    beeswax: Array,
    df: Array 
});
```

hs2_10010Schema.js

```
var conn = require('mongoose');

module.exports = conn.model('hiveserver2_10010', {
    snapShotTime : String,
    hs2: Array
});
```

Router.js

```
var moment = require('moment'); //add moment

var records;
//mongoose schema
var appTableProdSchema = require("./appTableProdSchema.js");
var hs2 = require("./hs2_10010Schema.js");

router.get('/getHealthReport', function(req, res) {
    // Return the most recent document
    var fullData = [];
    records = appTableProdSchema
                   .find()
                   .sort({'_id': -1})
                   .limit(1)
                   .exec(function(err, data) {
                        if (err) return res.sendStatus(500);
                        fullData.push(data);
                   });


    records = hs2
               .find()
               .sort({'_id': -1})
               .limit(1)
               .exec(function(err, data) {
                    if (err) return res.sendStatus(500);
                    fullData.push(data);
                    res.json(fullData);
               }); 

    }); 

module.exports = router;
```

The data that i see in Response is:

```
[
    [{
        "_id":"56f178cf64dadf6411ccc3fa",
        "snapShotTime":"2016-03-22-16:50:05",
        "__v":0,
        "df":["data_node_1","data_node_2","data_node_3","data_node_4","data_node_5","data_node_13","data_node_10","data_node_9","data_node_6","data_node_8","data_node_12","data_node_7","data_node_11","ebdp-ch2-d146p.sys.comcast.net","ebdp-ch2-d192p.sys.comcast.net"],
        "beeswax":["data_node_10","data_node_1","data_node_11","data_node_13","data_node_4","data_node_2","data_node_3","data_node_6","data_node_12","data_node_5","data_node_7","data_node_8"],
        "hs2":["data_node_7","data_node_1","data_node_10","data_node_13","data_node_4","data_node_3","data_node_2","data_node_9","data_node_11","data_node_5","data_node_8","data_node_6","data_node_12"],
        "beeline":["data_node_10","data_node_1","data_node_11","data_node_13","data_node_4","data_node_2","data_node_3","data_node_6","data_node_12","data_node_5","data_node_7","data_node_8"],
        "hive":["data_node_4","data_node_2","data_node_3","data_node_7","data_node_8","data_node_5","data_node_1","data_node_6","data_node_12","data_node_11","data_node_13","data_node_9","data_node_10"],
        "nfs":["data_node_7","data_node_4","data_node_1","data_node_3","data_node_10","data_node_5","data_node_13","data_node_9","data_node_11","data_node_6","data_node_8","data_node_12","data_node_2"]
        }],

    [{
        "_id":"56f178cf64dadf6411ccc3fb",
        "snapShotTime":"2016-03-22 16:50:05",
        "__v":0,
        "hs2":["data_node_9"]
    }]
]
```

How do i code to get the json objects from the array ?

Answer (score 0):

Array in JSON objects have a function getJSONObject(int index), you can loop through all of them using for-loop:

```
var array;
for(int n = 0; n < array.length(); n++)
   {
       var object = array.getJSONObject(n);
       // do some stuff....
   }
```

Comment: I guess in javascript scripting i cannot use JSONArray and JSONObject. This is done in java.

Comment: It should work. If it does not then you can create a custom iterator. Then you should be able to go through the json array. You can have a look at :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators

Comment: Please use a proper javascript syntax, as this is a syntax error in javascript. Javascript doesn't support declaring variables with types. You can do `var array;` and `var object = array.getJSONObject(n);` instead, if that is what you are trying to do.